# Select, calculate, create and insert

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hana

I have a huge table and I would like to loop through each row, do the following calculation and insert the new value in a new column.

```
For example:

Old_Table1:

Product      Quantity     Price
  TV            20         350€

New_Table:

Product      Quantity     Price   TOtal
  TV            20         350€    7000€
```

How to write a query to do the following.

If anyone familiar with implementing the same with HANA then it would be great.

Comment: Tell me you don't store the Euro symbol! And what is 'huge'? And why store data that can be so easily calculated 'on-the-fly'

Comment: Hey strawberry, Yes that euro symbol was just an example to make it more clear. NOrmally it should be just value i.e 7000. "HUGE" refers to million rows for instace.

Comment: is there any reason not to use a view instead of the new table? like `create view new_view as select product, quantity, price, quantity*price as total from old_table`?

Comment: Well, basically I am writing a stored procedure in HANA database. I am new to writing business logic. Now I am in a situation where I have a value in a variable and I need to update it in a new column. If it is a view or a table, that doesnt matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
AS 
(
SELECT Product, Quantity, Price, (Quantity*Price) AS Total 
FROM old_table
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88fde/1)

ANOTHER WAY:

```
ALTER TABLE old_table ADD COLUMN (Total Float);

UPDATE old_table SET Total = Quantity*Price;
```

[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a421/1)

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use a cursor.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) you can find more about it with example.